# Most idiomatic way to do validation on type

Tags: javascript

I am used to using something like the following pattern on a dynamic language to check/assert type:

```
function square(num) {
    // pretend we don't already have a TypeError
    if (!num instanceof Number) throw new MyCustomError("Only a number is allowed here") 
    return num * num;
}
```

However, js doesn't allow `instanceof` on primitives, well, at least in a way that helps check the type easily such as I'd want in the above. What is the recommended/idiomatic way to do this, just compare to a string? Such as:

```js
// create our own error
class ValidationError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "ValidationError";
  }
}

function square(num) {
  // pretend we don't want a TypeError
  if (typeof num != 'number')
    throw new ValidationError("Only a number is allowed here") 
  return num * num;
}

console.log(square(2));
console.log(square('abc'));
```

Comment: Do you want to accept number *objects* or number *primitives*? `instanceof` for objects and `typeof` for primitives. If you want both, then you can use both.

Comment: `!num` is a boolean and a primitive. It’s not an instance of anything, especially not of `Number`. `typeof num !== "number"` is the correct check.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#using_tostring_to_detect_object_class

Comment: @VLAZ what do you mean by a number object? An object that contains a number? Or something else.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 `new Number(42)` vs `42`.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 [new Number() vs Number()](/q/4719320/4642212), [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number).

Comment: `if (isNaN(num)) throw ...` allows for a more generic `num` input. Like strings that could be treated like numbers. eg. `square("foo") //=> throws error`, `square("10") //=> 100`, `square(8) //=> 64` or objects that implement a `valueOf()` method `square({ valueOf: () => 4 }) //=> 16`. For strict type restrictions you should probably look at TypeScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if a variable is not a `Number` by doing an `instanceof` check (which does not work on primitives), try the following.

```js
const num = 78;
console.log(isNaN(num) || typeof num !== "number");
```

In here, we are using the `typeof` keyword, as it is supported by JavaScript primitives. We are also checking if the value is `NaN`.

Comment: `typeof NaN === 'number'; // true`

Comment: Fixed it! I used `||` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reusable decorator function that makes any function which only accepts numeric parameters throw an error if called with non-numeric arguments:

```js
function multiply(a, b) { return a * b }

function numArgsOnly(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    if (args.some(n => n!==Number(n))) 
      throw `${args.find(n => n!==Number(n))} is not a number`;
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

const safeMultiply = numArgsOnly(multiply);

console.log(safeMultiply(3,9));

try {
  safeMultiply(3,'foo');
} catch (e) { console.error(e) }
```